# SharedArray Deadlock and raise Conditions

Tags: java, concurrency, deadlock, reentrantlock

I'm trying to stimulate the scenario of deadlocks in the shared array using Reentrant Locks.

```
class SharedArray { 
    private int ff[];
    private Lock keys[];        

    public SharedArray(int n){
        ff = new int[n];
        keys = new ReentrantLock[n];
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            ff[j] = (int)(Math.random()*100);
            keys[j] = new ReentrantLock();
        }
    }

    void swap(int j, int k) { 
        keys[j].lock(); keys[k].lock(); 
        int t = ff[j]; ff[j] = ff[k]; ff[k] = t;
        keys[j].unlock(); keys[k].unlock(); 
    }       
}
```

Here the swap method is deadlock prone which I have achieved. for example if Thread 1 is swap(7,4) and at the same time Thread 2 is swap(4,7) this will raised the deadlock.

How do I prevent it from deadlock. What sort of refactoring is required. I have tried to used synchronized but I'm looking for possibly a reliable way to solve that.

```
synchronized void swap(int j, int k) { 
    keys[j].lock(); keys[k].lock(); 
    int t = ff[j]; ff[j] = ff[k]; ff[k] = t;
    keys[j].unlock(); keys[k].unlock(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I prevent it from deadlock?

One way to prevent deadlock would be to ensure that any threads that acquire the same two locks always will acquire them in the same order.

```
void swap(int j, int k) {
    int first = Math.min(j, k);
    int second = Math.max(j, k);
    keys[first].lock(); keys[second].lock(); 
    int t = ff[j]; ff[j] = ff[k]; ff[k] = t;
    keys[second].unlock(); keys[first].unlock(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to employ lock ordering. If you lock each time in a predictable order you can prevent dead locking.

Found in Java Concurrency In Practice, you can see an example of how to achieve this:

```
public void transferMoney(final Account fromAcct, final Account toAcct, final DollarAmount amount)
        throws InsufficientFundsException {
    class Helper {
        public void transfer() throws InsufficientFundsException {
            if (fromAcct.getBalance().compareTo(amount) < 0)
                throw new InsufficientFundsException();
            else {
                fromAcct.debit(amount);
                toAcct.credit(amount);
            }
        }
    }
    int fromHash = System.identityHashCode(fromAcct);
    int toHash = System.identityHashCode(toAcct);
    if (fromHash < toHash) {
        synchronized (fromAcct) {
            synchronized (toAcct) {
                new Helper().transfer();
            }
        }
    } else if (fromHash > toHash) {
        synchronized (toAcct) {
            synchronized (fromAcct) {
                new Helper().transfer();
            }
        }
    } else {
        synchronized (tieLock) {
            synchronized (fromAcct) {
                synchronized (toAcct) {
                    new Helper().transfer();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3650/4bc31d3b2c5c00e5bfee28ffc5d403cc8edd.pdf, search for Listing 10.3. Inducing a Lock Ordering to Avoid Deadlock.